# Problems with GoDaddy domain using Google Apps solution

Tags: domain, g-suite, godaddy, domain-transferring

Some time ago using Google Apps, I bought the domain bindsolution.com.
I saw it was a field of GoDaddy.

Today I hired the services of GoDaddy hosting but it seems that both accounts are not the same.

I need to transfer my domain to be used with the hosting I just hire.

How do I do this? I have to do some setup in DNS?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options:

- Merge these GoDaddy accounts into 1
- Transfer domain from one account to another

These are the options that I was doing once in the past -- over 2 years ago.

You may be able to just point your DNS records to correct server IP, but you have to check your Control Panel for this (I do not have any hosting accounts with GoDaddy and cannot confirm it).